# Why insert style again on client-side when using ssr? (from MUI docs)

Tags: material-ui, server-side-rendering, emotion

I was going through [Mui's Server-side Rendering DOCS](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/server-rendering/).
And It says to prevent FOUC, we should inject style to rendered HTML on server side.
This was very clear.

But after that, it says "On the client-side, the CSS will be injected a second time before removing the server-side injected CSS."

this is the part I don't get.

why should we inject CSS again on client-side if it's already injected server-side?
Is there any difference between client-side cache and server-side cache?

And what is benefit of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, it would be that if some new Material UI element appears during runtime, the client needs to be able to handle that. SSR after all is for the initial loading of the page. So basically it is client rerendered to allow being dynamic.

This however creates issues for me personally as well since the new  tag overwrites my Tailwind . Am trying to figure out how to render the client version above/before the Tailwind one, hence is why your question popped up on Google.

**Edit:** If I remember correctly, I solved using emotion; https://emotion.sh/docs/ssr